# Blender 3.1 getting slower and slower on startup, what is the cause of this?

Tags: add-on

I have noticed Blender's load times getting slower for some reason and Im trying to understand what is at the core of this issue. I have heard this is most likely due to add ons.  Thoughts?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just tried launching 2.93 and 3.1.  Both took about 7-8 secs on my platform (https://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/22017930  Acer 885 with zippy i5-8400  16 GB, modest Nvidia GTX 1050).  R U opening a certain blend file or start with empty?

Comment: It was lagging on both. After a recent update its been fine again.  I have a Threadripper 3990x / 64G ram / Nvidia RTX 5000